# How to do .configure and make install in yocto?

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I need to install an open-source tool.

In build procedure, I see it need to do as follows:

```
  ./configure
  make -j48
  make -j48 install
```

I don't know how to translate these into yocto recipe.

*make* seems can be replaced by *oe_runake*? How about the *./configure*?

Comment: `inherit autotools`

Answer (score 3):

It's really easy, just put `inherit autotools` somewhere in your recipe, and everything will be done automatically. You don't need to write a `do_configure`, `do_compile` or `do_install` task, all that is already included in the `autotools` class.

As an example, look at the [libyaml recipe](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/recipes-support/libyaml/libyaml_0.2.5.bb) of the Poky distribution:

```
SUMMARY = "LibYAML is a YAML 1.1 parser and emitter written in C."
DESCRIPTION = "LibYAML is a C library for parsing and emitting data in YAML 1.1, \
a human-readable data serialization format. "
HOMEPAGE = "https://pyyaml.org/wiki/LibYAML"
SECTION = "libs/devel"

LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://License;md5=7bbd28caa69f81f5cd5f48647236663d"

SRC_URI = "https://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-${PV}.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "bb15429d8fb787e7d3f1c83ae129a999"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "c642ae9b75fee120b2d96c712538bd2cf283228d2337df2cf2988e3c02678ef4"

S = "${WORKDIR}/yaml-${PV}"

inherit autotools

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

For more detailed information and additional features about the autotools class, check the [Yocto Reference Manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-classes-autotools) or the [Yocto Application's Developer Guide](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0.3/adt-manual/adt-manual.html#autotools-based-projects).